# CakePHP - How to paging with json data?

Tags: json, cakephp

I'm training with CakePHP. Currently I have a problem.
I don't know how to paging with json data.
My application will call to API and receive JSON data.
The format look like

```
{"success":1,"films":[{"film_id":"384","title":"GROSSE WONDERFUL","description":"A Epic Drama of a Cat And a Explorer who must Redeem a Moose in Australia","release_year":"2006","language_id":"1","original_language_id":null,"rental_duration":"5","rental_rate":"4.99","length":"49","replacement_cost":"19.99","rating":"R","special_features":"Behind the Scenes","last_update":"2006-02-15 05:03:42"},{"film_id":"984","title":"WONDERFUL DROP","description":"A Boring Panorama of a Woman And a Madman who must Overcome a Butler in A U-Boat","release_year":"2006","language_id":"1","original_language_id":null,"rental_duration":"3","rental_rate":"2.99","length":"126","replacement_cost":"20.99","rating":"NC-17","special_features":"Commentaries","last_update":"2006-02-15 05:03:42"}]}
```

This is php code

```
$data = array('filmId' => $search_data['filmId'], 'filmTitle' => $search_data['filmTitle'], 'releaseYear' => $search_data['releaseYear'], 'rating' => $search_data['rating']);
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$records = $HttpSocket->post($apiFilmsByConditions, $data);
$records = json_decode($records, true);
```

I try to use paginate of CakePHP but it seems that this will get data from database, not from API.

**This is API link http://oxuhandmade.com/api/get_all_films.php**

Can you help me on this case?

Comment: You don't paginate an array. If the api you are using doesn't have pagination or some equivalent what you want is to split the array into chunks, and treat each  hunk as a page. **Implement caching**.

Comment: Unfortunately, the api doen't have pagination. Would you like to tell me more details about implement caching? (Sorry because I'm very new in CakePHP).

Comment: P.S: This is API link http://oxuhandmade.com/api/get_all_films.php

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the API query the database? An API is an "Application programming interface", meaning that it allows you to operate on the database from the "outside", based on a simple interface, triggered by some requests. So there is no point in wanting to limit the results via API, but *not* via database.

To limit the results an API returns, you need to pass a parameter together with your request, process it in the backend, query the database with the desired limit, and return the results to whoever made the request. Or simply hardcode the desired limit on the API, if it doesn't need to be dynamic.

The `Paginator` from CakePHP makes this work a whole lot easier, you only have to feed it some conditions and parameters for paginating the results, and it does the magic for you.

Comment: It seems unlikely the developer using whatever api is also a developer OF the api in the question. An api is just another datasource; bypassing an api (even if it were possible) to directly query the db (which is highly unlikely to be accessible) isn't the answer here

Comment: As I know, CakePHP always use datasource from database if we use default Paginator. In my case, I get data from API (http://oxuhandmade.com/api/get_all_films.php) and do the paging. How can I do this with the data return from API?

Comment: Alright, I misunderstood the question, I thought the OP was also designing the API. Since there is no control over what the API returns, the solution would be to split the returned array to smaller chunks, as @AD7six suggested.